# navigate back to a specific page in a paged ng2-smart-table after navigating away via a link in a cell

Tags: angular, angular7, ng2-smart-table

Does anyone have a decent way to track the current page, filters, etc of an ng2-smart-table in Angular 7, so that if the user clicks a cell that is a nav-link to a "more details" page,  so that when the browser "back" button is subsequently used, the table goes back to that page on ngInit, rather than going to the first page of the table with empty filters,  thus forcing the user to re-nav to the page he left from?

I have toyed with the idea of keeping a table of "last known state (filters and page)" for each of the different object listers,  as part of a cookie,  but this could get complicated.

Interested to hear how others have approached this.